# MySQL - select rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Query:

```
select 33, 12, 53;
```

Result:

```
+----+----+----+
| 33 | 12 | 53 |
+----+----+----+
| 33 | 12 | 53 |
+----+----+----+
```

Is it possible write query to receive:

```
+----+
| 33 |
+----+
| 33 |
| 12 |
| 53 |
+----+
```

without using union?

```
select 33 union select 12 union select 53;
```

Because it looks not very nice.

Comment: You want to union the date without unioning the data. I'm afraid you'll have to union the data in order for the data to be unioned.

Comment: Look, no `UNION`!! `SELECT DISTINCT CAST(RAND() * 100 AS UNSIGNED) AS n FROM tbl_with_thousands_of_rows HAVING n IN (33,12,53);` :-P  (although still not guaranteed to return all of them)

Comment: Union data without union data - sounds fun) but it's not my aim. I just show example how it can be reached, but i try to find alternative way...

Comment: But that's what this is called. When you have data stored in a record that you want to store, instead, in individual records of the same field. That transposition is called a Union. If you want to union data you have to union the data. There's not another way to do this because there is already a way to do this. And `select 33 union select 12 union select 53;` isn't that terrible looking. You could, instead, dump the data in excel, copy it, and then Paste Special -> Transpose. But I can assure you that the VBA needed for all of that is much uglier than your `UNION` statement.

Comment: Yes. You're absolutely right. But i mean not exactly it.) For example, i can reach this result without union by using temporary table: `create temporary table tmp (id int); insert into tmp values (33), (12), (33); select * from tmp;`  But it worse than union.

Comment: Do you want to return all this six (33, 12, 53, 33, 12, 53) values in that one row or only three (33, 12, 53)?

Comment: I don't want one row, i want receive three rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the data (use a `TEMPORARY TABLE` if needed) then select it would be the easiest option without using `UNION`.

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    (`33` int)
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
    (`33`)
VALUES
    (33),
    (12),
    (53)
;

SELECT * 
FROM yourtable;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+----+
| 33 |
+----+
| 33 |
| 12 |
| 53 |
+----+
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edaba9/1/0

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. I do in some cases exactly as you described...)